# Datalist Auto Complete IE vs Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-datalist

I have an issue with my Datalist autocomplete I created, if you run it in Chrome you can search by name or ID, so for example you can type in Doe and get result for John Doe. or you can type in 11109 and it will give you John Doe.
In IE you can only type in the ID not the name to get results. 
Additionally I am sure there is not much that can be done with this but in Chrome the dropdown shows the ID and the Name next to each other where IE only shows the Name. 
How if at all possible can I get IE to work more like Chrome in both situations (I am more concerned with the searching by both ID and Name)

```js
 var json = [{
 "UserID": 17,
 "PSID": "1110959",
 "Name": "Doe, John",
 "Email": "John.Doe@somesite.com",
 "Level": "25",
 "Manager_Name": "Doe, Jane",
 "Manager_PSID": "1014009",
 "Manager_Email": "Jane.Doe@somesite.com",
 "Manager_Level": "19",
 "CompFile": null
}, {
 "UserID": 50,
 "PSID": "1114187",
 "Name": "Smith,Kevin",
 "Email": "Kevin.Smith@somesite.com",
 "Level": "27",
 "Manager_Name": "Herman, Mike",
 "Manager_PSID": "1178148",
 "Manager_Email": "Mike.Herman@somesite.com",
 "Manager_Level": "25",
 "CompFile": null
}, {
 "UserID": 123,
 "PSID": "1119167",
 "Name": "Black, Clint",
 "Email": "Clint.Black@somesite.com",
 "Level": "19",
 "Manager_Name": "Dwezel,Beth",
 "Manager_PSID": "1001375",
 "Manager_Email": "Beth.Dwezel@somesite.com",
 "Manager_Level": "43",
 "CompFile": null
}];
 
 $('#EmployeeSearch').on('keyup', function (e) {
            var term = this.value;
            //delay(function () {
               
            //}, 1000);
            $('#huge_list').empty();
         
                    $.each(json, function (i, item) {
                        $('<option/>', {
                            'value': item.PSID,
                            'text': item.Name
                        }).appendTo('#huge_list');
                    });
               
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="EmployeeSearch" list="huge_list" />
    <datalist id="huge_list"></datalist>
```

Comment: Datalist support in browsers isn't very consistent yet unfortunately. Might have to do something a bit more customized like jQuery autocomplete or something similar.

Comment: Jquery Autocomplete is not exactly what I was looking for. I tried it out and for the more complex stuff that I am looking to do it doesn't seem to work well. as a side note another issue I just found between the two. 
in Chrome I can search for "Doe, John" by typing in "John" but in IE you cannot type "John" you have to type it the way it is written so you have to start off with "Doe" or else you get no results.

I may have to go to a plugin that I found but would rather go with datalist if possible.